# In Windows XP, how can I get a list of all my hardware components as a text file?

Tags: windows-xp

I'll be putting Linux on my old Lenovo T60p laptop and I would like to have a list of all of the hardware in it, so that if I need to manually hunt down drivers, I have all of the make and model information for all the parts in my computer. Is there a way in Windows XP to export this list directly to a text file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download and run **[SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/)** - **System Information for Windows**

[image]

Under **Hardware**, expand **Devices**

Then go to **File** > **Create Report File** > **TXT**

For good measure, do the same with **PCI**

*SIW is freeware and portable.*

Comment: I'm assuming there's no way to do this in Windows?

Comment: not to TXT, no. but you can print from the device manager. however, SIW will give you far more comprehensive information. and you don't even have to install it, just run it from a USB stick.

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft's [The DevCon command-line utility functions as an alternative to Device Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272):

> The DevCon utility is a
>   command-line utility that acts as an
>   alternative to Device Manager. Using
>   DevCon, you can enable, disable,
>   restart, update, remove, and query
>   individual devices or groups of
>   devices. DevCon also provides
>   information that is relevant to the
>   driver developer and is not available
>   in Device Manager.

See [Using Devcon](http://robhaupt.blogspot.com/2008/07/using-devcon.html) for more info.

You may therefore use :

> devcon classes

to see which device classes are available, then use :

> devcon listclass USB

to list all USB devices on the computer.

You can also list all devices at once in a quite voluminous listing.